Confusion over disk partitions on Windows
I recently installed a new SSD into my PC and downloaded Windows 11 into the new disk. I originally left the old OS on the old disk in order to make sure I didn't delete anything I might need but at this point I am pretty sure I have everything. I am now looking to format the partition. In the screenshot provided it shows Disk 0 (unrelated HDD), Disk 1 which is the original disk with the old version of Windows on it, and Disk 2 which is the new SSD with the new Windows install.
My confusion comes from the partitions on Disk 1. Disk 2 (the new one) shows only one partition labelled "Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Basic Data Partition)" whereas Disk 1 has 3 partitions "Healthy(EFI System Partition)", "Healthy (Basic Data Partition)", "Healthy (Recovery Partition)".
I would quite like to have Disk 1 to house Linux
and it seems odd to leave parts of Windows on that disk if Disk 2 is where the rest of my OS is. Is there some way to move these partitions to Disk 2 or generate them again or am I misunderstanding what they do.
Sorry I haven't done a good job of explaining myself. Let me know if there is any confusion and I will try and explain better.
disk management screenshot


Only disk 1 can boot into Windows since it contains the EFI partition for both installs. You’ll want to correct that fact before doing anything with it. In its current state if anything happen to Disk 1, Disk 2, would not boot into Windows

Is there a relatively pain free way of doing this?

Since you just installed Windows. I would reinstall Windows with the other device disconnected.

I wouldn't say I just installed windows. I have been using it for maybe a month already

What I suggest surrounding fixing the EFI partition isn't trivial to resolve. Resolving the problem by reinstalling Windows correctly instead of installing a second copy reliant on the existing EFI partition is much easier.

There are multiple threads on the site about moving an EFI system partition (or the Windows parts thereof), and likewise about moving a Windows Recovery partition... It takes about 10 minutes for the "quick" option, although with your multi-terabyte C:\ it would take several hours for the "make it look tidy" option.

To test this answer, I first installed Windows 10 on one drive, then installed Windows 11 on a different drive. The created a Windows 10 and Windows 11 dual boot. The steps to replace Windows 10 with Linux are given below.

Install Windows 11 boot files on drive containing Windows 11.
Boot to Windows 11. Open an Administrator Command Prompt window. Enter the command given below.
diskpart

This command is interactive. Enter what is shown below. Basically, you are adding an EFI partition to the drive containing Windows 11. Here, I assume this drive already has a Microsoft Reserved partition.
select volume c:
shrink desired=300
create partition efi
format fs=fat32 label=EFI quick
assign letter=s
exit

Next, enter the command below to install Windows 11 boot files on the volume stored in the new EFI partition.
bcdboot c:\windows /s s: /f uefi

You can close the Administrator Command Prompt window and restart the computer.

Enable Windows Recovery Environment
This step is optional. I found my Windows Recovery
Environment (WRE) was not enabled. This step corrected this problem. You can see if your WRE is enabled by entering the following command.
reagentc /info

To enable, I opened an Administrator Command Prompt window and entered the command given below.
reagentc /setreimage /path c:\recovery\windowsre /enable

You can close the Administrator Command Prompt window and shutdown the computer.

Install Linux on the drive containing Windows 10. I chose to install Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.1 LTS. When asked, I chose to erase the disk, as shown below.


After installing Linux, I needed to manually edit the firmware settings to make Ubuntu first in the boot order. I was able to choose between Windows and Ubuntu from the Grub menu, as shown below.




References

Answer to How do I change the UEFI Boot Order from within Windows 10?


Thanks for such an in-depth answer! I will give it a go this weekend and update. Just so I'm clear, the disk with windows 10 in your test starts off with the eif and recovery partitions and the disk with 11 just contains the c drive like in my screenshot? Does this answer consider the recovery partition or can it be ignored? Sorry if these are silly questions I just don't want to get it wrong!

When I installed Windows 10, the installer created EFI and Recovery partitions. A 16 MB Microsoft Reserve (MSR) partition was also created. When the Disk Management application displays partitions, the MSR is omitted. I assume your drive with Windows 10 has this small MSR partition. When I installed Windows 11, I created a single partition on a different drive. Installer also added a 16 MB MSR partition to the drive. This is probably also true for your Windows 11 installation.

So, to answer your questions, my Windows 11 Disk Management application showed the same partitions for the two Windows drives as shown in your screenshot. The Windows 11 disk just showed drive C:. My Windows 11 installation did not include a Recovery Partition. Instead, the files normally stored in a Recovery partition were installed in a hidden folder on drive C:. I assume you have the same situation. The Recovery partition shown in your screenshot should only be for Windows 10.

If you want to see if the Recovery files exist on drive C: when booted to Windows 11, enter dir /a:h c:\recovery\windowsre.
